# SQL AND and OR operators behave unexpected

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making the below query:

```sql
SELECT
    `user_organisation`.*,
    `users`.`full_name`,
    `users`.`email`,
    `users`.`avatar`
FROM
    `user_organisation`
INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `user_organisation`.`user_id`
WHERE
    `users`.`full_name` LIKE '%test%' OR `users`.`email` LIKE '%test%' AND `user_organisation`.`organisation_id` = 111
```

And I get the results containing `user_organisation.organisation_id` equals `111` and `222`. I want to search records with `users.full_name` or `users.email` containing value `test`. This SQL successfully searches users with full name or email containing string `test` but not only `user_organisation.organisation_id=111`.

What the reason for that unexpected behaviour? I sure I'm missing something but I can't see...

Comment: WHERE
  (  `users`.`full_name` LIKE '%test%' OR `users`.`email` LIKE '%test%') AND `user_organisation`.`organisation_id` = 111

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? If you still need help with the query, please share sample data

Comment: @NicoHaase question solved by Tim Biegelesen. I apparently forgot to wrap the or operator and the two operands within parantheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parentheses in your `WHERE` clause around the two `OR`ed terms:

```sql
SELECT uo.*, u.full_name, u.email, u.avatar
FROM user_organisation uo
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = uo.user_id
WHERE (u.full_name LIKE '%test%' OR u.email LIKE '%test%') AND
      uo.organisation_id = 111;
```

Note also that in my answer I am using table *aliases* (which are abbreviations for full table names).  Also, I removed the unnecessary backticks.